# C++ boost unable do include (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c++, boost, include

I used bootstrap and b2 to install boost, b2 gave me those two folders to include:

```
D:\Boost\boost_1_65_1
D:\Boost\boost_1_65_1\stage\lib
```

In the project properties, I added the first one to

> Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

and the second one to

> Linker > General > Library Search Directories

I'm still getting "No such file or directory" when including for example:

```
#include <boost/archive/tmpdir.hpp>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: #include <boost/archive/tmpdir.hpp>

Comment: Also this error appear if you use double-qoute instead of `<>`? (i.e `#include "boost/archive/tmpdir.hpp"`)

Comment: Do you have a path like `D:\Boost\boost_1_65_1\include`?

Comment: What is the full path in your filesystem to tmpdir.hpp?

Comment: The error is the same if i put the include in double-qoutes.

Comment: D:\Boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\archive\tmpdir.hpp is the full path

Comment: @Helmet does this at least work? (Just checking, not a permanent solution): `#include "D:/Boost/boost_1_65_1/archive/tmpdir.hpp"`?

Comment: No, #include "D:/Boost/boost_1_65_1/archive/tmpdir.hpp" does not work too. IntelliSense recognizes the path while typing. Maybe i should mention that the project itself is placed in c:\dev\test

Comment: Ok, i foud out the following: If i create a new project it works fine, in my existing project, which is a linux one with VisualGbd, it does not work.